# Mailitem Move Error When Moving Message to a Different Folder in Outlook Using VB.net

Tags: vb.net, outlook, com-interop

Mailitem Move Error When Moving Message to a Different Folder in Outlook Using VB.net

I keep running into an error in Outlook when trying to move MailItems using Outlook Com Interop in VB.net.  I'm not having any issues accessing the messages, reading them, or getting the related folders, it's just that I get this error when trying to move messages intermittently.

Here is the error message reported by the application:

```
 `System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException(0x80040107): The operation failed. at Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook_Mailitem.Move(MAPIFolderDestFldr) at ApplicationName.MainWindow.EmailImport() at System.Threading....`
```

Well, you get the idea.

Here is the related code:

```
Dim OutlookAp As New Outlook.Application
Dim NS As Outlook.Namespace = OutlookAp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Dim ObjFolder As Outlook.Folder
Dim Inbox As Outlook.Folder
Dim CEBFolder As Outlook.Folder
Dim DestinationFolder As Outlook.Folder
Dim Mesg As Outlook.Mailitem
```

Here's how I get the folders:

```
For Each ObjFolder in NS.Folders
    If ObjFolder.Name = "CEB Folder Name" Then
        CEBFolder = ObjFolder
        Exit For
    End If
Next ObjFolder
```

EDIT:  Including the rest of the folders:

```
For Each ObjFolder in CEBFolder.Folders
    If ObjFolder.Name = "Inbox" then
        Inbox = ObjFolder
        Exit For
    End If
Next ObjFolder

For Each ObjFolder in Inbox.Folders
    If ObjFolder.Name = "Destination Folder" then
        DestinationFolder = ObjFolder
        Exit For
    End If
Next ObjFolder
```

And so on.  Here's how I'm moving the message:

```
For Counter = Inbox.Items.Count to 1 Step -1
    If TypeName(Inbox.Items(Counter)) = "MailItem" then
        Mesg = Ctype(Inbox.Items(Counter), Outlook.MailItem)
        'Do some parsing of the message
        Mesg.Move(DestinationFolder)
    End If
Next Counter
```

And that's pretty much it.  This code seems to be successful most of the time, but every now and again Outlook simply won't let me move a message, full stop.

As always, any ideas are greatly appreciated.

Comment: The error is MAPI_E_INVALID_ENTRYID, whcih means the item is already gone (e.g. a new message was moved by a rule or the user)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're never assigning `DestinationFolder`, so you're trying to move the message to `Null`.

Comment: I just omitted that code because it got repetitive, but i can include it if you think it would be helpful.  I have, however, set the destination folder and verified that the object is loading properly.

Comment: I've edited the question above to make it clear that I'm getting all the folders.  Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

You appar not to be able to move MailItems which are system responses to undelivered e-mail etc. They appear as MailItem type but appear not to support moving between folders - perhaps they are virtual mail items. See threads elsewhere on handling undelivered messages